# How to Group By all fields nested tables in a Left Join query in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, nested-table

I have about 10 tables that I make one big nested tables by rounds with the following query:

```
   R1 AS(
      SELECT ANY_VALUE(Table1).*, ARRAY_AGG(( SELECT AS STRUCT Table2.* EXCEPT(ID))) AS Table2
      FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 USING(ID)
      GROUP BY Table1.ID),

   R2 AS(
      SELECT ANY_VALUE(R1).*, ARRAY_AGG(( SELECT AS STRUCT Table3.* EXCEPT(ID))) AS Table3
      FROM R1 LEFT JOIN Table3 USING(ID)
      GROUP BY R1.ID),
...

  
   SELECT ANY_VALUE(R9).*, ARRAY_AGG(( SELECT AS STRUCT Table10.* EXCEPT(ID))) AS Table10
   FROM R9 LEFT JOIN Table10 USING(ID)
```

The thing is that for example in my first table I can have two records with the same ID but some other fields will be different and I want to consider them as two distinct records and thus group by all the fields of the table while I join.
Then I want to do the same with all the "sub-table" (the R tables in the query), so I will able to group by all the fields of the nested tables.

How can I do it easily ?

I tried  `GROUP BY Table1.*` but it doesn't work...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [to_json_string](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#to_json_string):

```
...
FROM Table1 t1
...
GROUP BY to_json_string(t1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want something like this:

```
select *
from table1 t1 left join
     (select t2.*
      from table2 t2
      where true
      qualify row_number() over (partition by t2.id order by t2.id) = 0
     ) t2
     using (id)
```

This uses `qualify` instead of `group by` to fetch one row.

If you don't want all rows from from `table1`, you can whittle them down as well:

```
select *
from (select t1.* 
      from table1 t1
      where true
      qualify row_number() over (partition by id, col1, col2 order by id) = 1
     ) t1 left join
     (select t2.*
      from table2 t2
      where true
      qualify row_number() over (partition by t2.id order by t2.id) = 0
     ) t2
     using (id)
```

Comment: How do I create nested data with this ? Should I insert it instead of my R1 AS() part ?

Comment: What does the line `qualify row_number() over (partition by t2.id order by t2.id) = 0` do exactly ? Why to use it in the subquery ?

Comment: @Harvey . . . You can select whatever you want.  This addresses the your question which about returning one match from `table2` for each row in `table1`.

Answer (score 1):

> How to Group By all fields ...?
> I tried  GROUP BY Table1.* but it doesn't work...

Consider below example

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(t1).*, 
  ARRAY_AGG(( SELECT AS STRUCT t2.* EXCEPT(ID))) AS Table2
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 USING(ID)
GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', t1)
```